# Read an image file as greyscale byte array

Tags: array, vb.net

I use the Emgu.CV wrapper to create a grayscale image. The data of this image are to be copied into a 2D byte array. Is there a more elegant solution than mine?
I'm asking here at *CodeReview* because my code works and the question is therefore not suitable for *Stackoverflow*.

If you want to reproduce this: You need the files `Emgu.CV`, `Emgu.CV.Bitmap` and `Emgu.CV.runtime.windows` from Visual Studio's own NuGet package manager.

```
Imports Emgu.CV

Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Shared LoadedImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
        LoadedImage = New Drawing.Bitmap("C:\Users\Name\Desktop\test1.png")

        Using bgr As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Byte) = LoadedImage.ToImage(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Byte)
            Using imgGray As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte) = bgr.Convert(Of Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte)()
                'in ein 2D-Array kopieren
                Dim f(imgGray.Height - 1, imgGray.Width - 1) As Byte
                For y As Integer = 0 To imgGray.Height - 1 Step 1
                    For x As Integer = 0 To imgGray.Width - 1 Step 1
                        f(y, x) = imgGray.Data(y, x, 0)
                    Next
                Next

                ' do something with f(,)

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's great - a good title really helps attract the right reviewers.  Sorry it's not a language I've ever used, otherwise I would attempt a review myself.

Comment: Would _C#_ help you?

Comment: No, I'm mainly C++, C and shell, with a sprinkling of Python and Lisp.  But I do think you will get a review from someone more capable than me, so don't worry.

Answer (score 5):

## Separating UI from business logic

You have put everything into the button click event handler. This is really bad practice. Consider creating a separate class to handle the image processing:

```vb
Class ImageProcessor

    Public Function Process(inputFilePath As String) As String
        Dim rawData As Color(,) = LoadImage(inputFilePath)
        Dim grayData As Byte(,) = ConvertToGrayscale(rawData)
        Process = DoMagicOnImage(grayData)
    End Function

    Private Function LoadImage(inputFilePath As String) As Color(,)
        ...    
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertToGrayscale(src As Color(,)) As Byte(,)
        ....
    End Function

    Private Function DoMagicOnImage(src As Byte(,)) As String
        ....
    End Function

End Class
```

And changing `ButtonStart_Click` to the following:

```vb
Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
     Dim inputFilePath As String = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\test1.png";
     Dim processor As ImageProcessor = new ImageProcessor
     Dim result As String = processor.Process(inputFilePath)
End Sub
```

## Disposing of Disposable objects.

If you click on `ButtonStart` enough times your program is bound to crash in a bad way. You should always dispose of disposable objects such as `Drawing.Bitmap`.

I see you are already disposing of `bgr` and `imgGray` so why not do the same for `LoadedImage`?

## Implementation

Here you will have to excuse my rudimentary knowledge of Visual basic =)

```vb
Class ImageProcessor

    Public Function Process(inputFilePath As String) As String
        Dim rawData As Color(,) = LoadImage(inputFilePath)
        Dim grayData As Byte(,) = ConvertToGrayscale(rawData)
        Process = DoMagicOnImage(grayData)
    End Function

    Private Function LoadImage(inputFilePath As String) As Color(,)
        Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(inputFilePath)
            ' Lock the bitmap data.
            Dim bounds As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
            Dim bmpData As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(bounds, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
            ' Allocate room for the data.
            Dim total_size As Integer = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height
            ' Copy the data into the imageBytes array.
            Dim imageBytes As Byte()
            ReDim imageBytes(total_size)
            Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, imageBytes, 0, total_size)
            ' Copy imagesBytes into color array
            Dim multiDim As Color(,)
            ReDim multiDim(bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
            Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
            For y = 0 To bmp.Height - 1
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = y * bmpData.Stride
                For x = 0 To bmp.Width - 1
                    Dim r As Integer = imageBytes(rowIndex + x * 3 + 2)
                    Dim g As Integer = imageBytes(rowIndex + x * 3 + 1)
                    Dim b As Integer = imageBytes(rowIndex + x * 3 + 0)
                    multiDim(x, y) = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
                Next
            Next
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)
            LoadImage = multiDim
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertToGrayscale(src As Color(,)) As Byte(,)
        Dim Width As Integer = src.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim Height As Integer = src.GetUpperBound(1)
        Dim data As Byte(,)
        ReDim data(Width, Height)
        For y As Integer = 0 To Height - 1
            For x As Integer = 0 To Width - 1
                Dim col As Color
                col = src(x, y)
                data(x, y) = (col.R * 0.3 + col.G * 0.59 + col.B * 0.11)
            Next
        Next
        ConvertToGrayscale = data
    End Function

    Public Sub TestFunction(inputFilePath As String, outputFile As String)
        Dim colorData As Color(,) = LoadImage(inputFilePath)
        Dim grayData As Byte(,) = ConvertToGrayscale(colorData)
        Dim Width As Integer = grayData.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim Height As Integer = grayData.GetUpperBound(1)
        Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
            For y = 0 To Height - 1
                For x = 0 To Width - 1
                    Dim pixel As Byte = grayData(x, y)
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixel, pixel, pixel))
                Next
            Next
            bmp.Save(outputFile)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: In `LoadImage()` you need to call `UnlockBits()` on the bitmap. In the same method you should take into account that it is possible that `BitmapData.Stride` may be negative. For `LockBits()` you shouldn't assume the passed `PixelFormat`, just pass the `Bitmap.Pixelformat` property. Otherwise good review!

Comment: @Heslacher, good points. I have updated the answer to use `UnlockBits`. I'm not really sure how to handle a negative stride correctly, to be honest =) Also will `r`,`g`, and `b` always be in this order or could it be different depending on endianness?

Comment: @Heslacher, I should probably have stopped the review at implementation. The OP will most likely be better of using `Emgu.CV` but I always like to understand how things work under the hood.

Comment: You should use `Math.Abs()` for handling the negative `Stride`. The order of r,g,b won't be different for depending on endianness. If the loaded Bitmap isn't 24bit but 32bit you would need to change `imageBytes(rowIndex + x * 3 + 2)` e.g to `imageBytes(rowIndex + x * 4 + 2)`. While I write this, I see that you have to have `Step 3` (24bit)/`Step 4` (32bit) for the inner loop.

Comment: @Heslacher, I would have fought that `LockBits` thunks the data into the pixel format that you specify. I have tried the code with an 8-bit .bmp file and it seems to work. Simply using the absolute value of the stride does not make sense, why would it then be negative in the first place?

Comment: [BitmapData.Stride](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) in the remarks section "If the stride is positive, the bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is bottom-up."

Comment: @Heslacher, does this look correct? [TIO](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwFAX3OcVbtkKCHkCh0IJZuNILJM1vE2hTSWK1p49ZCfbB7Gbe6uJLTVyr6HruKfFV9zm3bkZY3tIb@qCJkD7RSIHJAXp@tiopcU/BGcIFRzwseYayX3LGhsNOZd0Uaa9VxRFXcqNN4DgVtrqUN5WsaHSs/i9q1nkDOeT8BQ)

Comment: For converting the whole image to greyscale, you won't need to do this so complicated. You should just use `Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride)` instead of `bmpData.Stride`. One time for `total_size ` and one time for `rowIndex`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130838/discussion-between-upkajdt-and-heslacher).